# WPF show Blank Row on disabled DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like to force-show Blank Row (NewItemPlaceholer) on my `DataGrid`s regardless whether they are enabled or not. How can I achieve it?

```
<!--looks inconsistent when swithing CanEditList - Blank Row is missing here-->
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding CanEditList}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" Header="Text"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Edit: the `DataGrid` is meant to be disabled and re-enabled based on property of ViewModel.

Comment: `<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" />` is the simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: @BionicCode `CanUserAddRows` does not seem to have any effect in that regard, can you elaborate? The moment `DataGrid` is disabled (`IsEnabled="False"`) the blank row is removed, I would like to keep it at all times.

Comment: Then why are you disabling it?

Comment: @BionicCode it makes no sence in some Model states for the Datagrid to be interacted with. Also note it is keyboard-only app so the less stops are on Tab order, which cannot be used in any meaningful way, the better. As for why not just live with inconsistent UI, it is not just inconsitent but also higly incovenient -  DataGrid is unable to restore focus correctly if the focused item in the FocusScope was the placeholder before moving elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know enough details to criticize your design but it appeals to provide not a good user experience. Maybe you have too many controls on one single screen. The user would feel confused if there are tables that are disabled once a while. Maybe you should use pages to create a context based environment.

Comment: If you set the `DataGrid` to read-only and set `IsTabStop=False` the the table is no more interactive and won't receive focus via the Tab key.

Comment: @BionicCode agree it would definitely seem so from the description. However, because it is not classic pointer/touch UI we learned in user testing that many of the web-like UX priciples simply do not apply. There are no more than 3 areas of interest, most screens having two or less (e.g. master-detail). In order to enforce focus handling, simple KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation, TabOrder, TabStops etc. proved ineffective - the focus can (and will!) still escape the area in various ways ...unless there is nowhere to escape to (everything else is disabled)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197572/discussion-between-wondra-and-bioniccode).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `IsEnabled` property, you could set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false`.

This will keep the blank row. The other option would be add a blank row without any values to your `ItemsSource` collection.

Comment: Thanks, rolling own `NewItemPlaceholder` sounds like a starter good idea, though I am not sure how to approach it - it calls for rather complex `ViewModel`. Nevertheless I will try to explore this line of thinking. Sadly with `IsHitTestVisible` the DataGrid will be still editable with keyboard (and setting `IsReadonly` will yet again remove the placeholder).

Comment: @wondra: So what about my other suggestion of adding a blank item to your source collection?

Comment: I will try implementing the idea - need to track somehow it is written to in ViewModel, copy the values without switching focus/ handling de/selection, etc. etc. Rather complex solution to simple problem, but at least a lead.

Comment: I mean that you should add the empty object to the source collection in your view model.

Comment: Yeah, but when you edit it in the DataGrid, you need to catch row commited events so that you can add another new item ...and handle ordering/focus the focus correctly.

Comment: It should be editable if the `DataGrid` is. Datagrids can be editable, non-editable and those that are switched between either based on context. I might worded it in wrong way. I need the placeholder to stay but work as normal DataGrid in every other aspect imaginable.